# How do I redirect 'stdout' to 'stderr' and 'stderr' to 'stdout'?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, io-redirection

I want to redirect everything that is supposed to go to `stdout` to `stderr`, and everything that is going to `stderr` to go to `stdout` instead.

The following code does not work:

```
$ bin/stdout-test 1>&2 2>&1
```

---

I'm sure there is a practical use for this somewhere out there, but currently it's just a mental exercise to help learn and understand io redirection.

In Ubuntu, both `stdout` and `stderr` get redirected to the console anyway, so you can't really tell if you are making any progress, but the command `tcpserver` will redirect `stdout` to the connecting remote user, and `stderr` to the terminal that started the `tcpserver` session, making it a perfect place to test this type of redirection.

I created a test project just for this purpose:

- [*GitHub: IQAndreas-testprojects/stdout-stderr-testing*](https://github.com/IQAndreas-testprojects/stdout-stderr-testing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your attempt does not work because `1>&2` merges stdout into stderr, and after that there is no hope of ever separating them again.  You need a third temporary file descriptor to do the swap, like when swapping the values of two variables.

Use `exec` to move file descriptors.

```
( exec 3>&1- 1>&2- 2>&3- ; bin/stdout-test )
```

or just

```
bin/stdout-test 3>&1- 1>&2- 2>&3-
```

Explanation:

1. `3>&1-` moves stdout (FD 1) to FD 3
2. `1>&2-` moves stderr (FD 2) to FD 1
3. `2>&3-` moves FD 3 to stderr (FD 2)

See [Moving File Descriptors](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Moving-File-Descriptors).

Comment: FYI: This does not generally work in POSIX shells. The moving of FDs is a bash extension.